# Почему сортировка массива работает дольше 2 секунд?

Tags: сортировка, c++

Вот программа генерирующая тесты

```
int main()
{
    freopen("e.in", "w", stdout);

    cout << 1000000 << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        cout << rand() << ' ';

    return 0;   
}
```

Вот быстрая сортировка массива

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int a[1000100], n;

int main()
{
    freopen("e.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("e.out", "w", stdout);

    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    sort(a, a + n);

    return 0;   
}
```

Оценка этого алгоритм 10 ^ 6 * log(10 ^ 6) < 10 ^ 8, как она может так долго работатать????7

Comment: А теперь проверните такой финт на спектруме, за недельку отсортирует... возможно...

Comment: что ? ????

Comment: 10 ^ 8 - это что?

Comment: @Евгений536 намекаю на то что не стоит задавать вопрос о быстродействии определенного алгоритма на сферическом коне в вакуме замеряя его не в тактах а во времени которое зависит от конкретного коня.

Comment:  1. Как вы измеряли время выполнения?
 2. Подсчёт теоретического времени
    выполнения по тактам перестал быть
    актуальным с момента ухода 8086 с
    домашних компьютеров, в котором ещё
    было наивное последовательное
    выполнение всего и вся.


Comment: время выполнения измеряла тестирующая система! 
10 ^ 8 = 1000000000 в данном случае я имел ввиду кол-во итерация выполняемых алгоритмов, что очень даже допустимо и должно работать меньше одной секунды

Comment: Все дело в `cin >> a[i]`
когда изменил на `scanf("%d", &a[i])` к удивлению стал отлично работать!
может кто подскажет, неужели `cin` такой медленный??

Comment: вывести миллион элементов - не быстрое дело. Возможно, printf имеет более эффективные методы буферизации в данном случае.

Comment: всмысле? как это можно ускорить?

Comment: @Евгений536, а что Вы хотели от крестов?

Обобщенное программирование плохо сочетается со скоростью исполнения. 

Используйте ввод-вывод из Си (<stdio.h>, в Вашем случае видимо fscanf()).

Comment: @KoVadim: не вывести, ввести! У меня почему-то подозрение, что ТС как-то не вполне правильно измеряет время.

Comment: @Евгений536 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio
старо как мир

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Медленно работает не сортировка, а считывание данных. 
В начале программы добавьте:

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```